# Resetting Unused column to used in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

A column in a table is marked as `UNUSED`. I want it to make it a regular column (as used) again, for accessing it by `SELECT`.

I know that next step of `UNUSED` is `DROP`.

But is there any way that I can retrieve the data from the `UNUSED` column ?

Comment: No. Unless you restore the table before the column was set to unused. This does not work `alter table yourtable set used columns sex;` it produces an ora error (`ORA-02000: missing UNUSED keyword`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "is there any way that I can retrieve the data from the UNUSED column ?"

No.  The SET UNUSED syntax is a convenience for DBAs. Dropping a column is potentially a resource-intensive exercise. Marking it as UNUSED is a lot quicker, so it allows them to withdraw a column from use in busy times and run DROP UNUSED when the database is quieter.  But the data is as lost as if they had just dropped the column.

The only way to retrieve the data would be to restore the column, through one of the [various Flashback features](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS1008) (depending on what you've got configured) or else RMAN (or whichever Backup/Recovery solution you have in place).